# Как представить четырехмерный массив?

Tags: c++

**Двумерный массив:**

int mas[2][3] =

{

{1,2,3},

{1,2,3},

}

Т.е. 3 значения и 2 строки.

**Трехмерный массив:**

int mas[4][2][3]=

{

{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},

{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},

}

Т.е. тоже самое что двумерный массив только 4 измерения.

А как представить и записать в таком формате 4 мерный массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mas[2][2][2][2] =
{
  {
    {
      {1,2},{1,2}
    },
    {
      {1,2},{1,2}
    }
  },
  {
    {
      {1,2},{1,2}
    },
    {
      {1,2},{1,2}
    }
  }
}
```